# Is "voluntary accommodation" common?

Tags: eye, vision, ophthalmology, optometry

I can't find any resource online about what I call **"voluntary accommodation"**: the ability to contract the lens of the eye manually in order to blur or clear the vision. My optician advised me to ask a ophthalmologist but where I live, they are overbooked and expensive.

**So, is the ability to contract the lens common?**

[Accommodation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accommodation_(eye)) is a natural and automatic process made by the muscle inside the eye in order to focus the vision. My question is about contracting manually that muscle. Apparently not so many people can.

Comment: That is my first post on StackExchange, I'm sorry that my question wasn't clear. My question was: "is the ability to contract his crystallin common?"
I edited my post.

Comment: I think the point of confusion here is simply the word "crystallin." Crystallin isn't a muscle; it's a protein that creates the clear structure of your eye's lens and cornea. So I edited the question to replace a complicated word with a simple word. I hope that makes your intent clear.

Comment: Thank you @CareyGregory, indeed **that's clearer** (no joke about that).
I found a similar topic on Reddit with -some parts- of answer. Actually many people can contract manually their eye's lens. I found a comment a interesting : "I think the eye focus [...] is just learning how to control a muscle that people dont usually use. Its like when people can move their ears or flex one pectoral at a time."
I agree that this muscle can be controlled by everyone but not everyone does it, like moving your ear. However I'm still looking forward for a more detailed answer to my question.

Comment: The actual Reddit topic : https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/23zz2b/eli5_why_can_i_control_the_focus_of_my_eyes_i_can/